# Powershell defaultparameterset not working. error

Tags: powershell, default-parameters, parameter-sets

I am trying to use parameter set and use default parameter set. But the default parameter set doesn't seem to work for me. Any help is much appreciated. I can easily use validate set with default action but I want to know what I am doing wrong here.

```
Param([cmdletbinding(DefaultParametersetname="Directory")] 
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="File")]
      [switch]$file, 
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="Directory")]  
      [switch]$directory,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="File")] 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="Directory")] 
[string]$Source,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="File")]  
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="Directory")] 
[string]$DestinationPath, 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="Directory")] 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="File")]
[array]$Servers

PS C:\> Test-Script -Source "c:\somedirectory" -DestinationPath "c:\someotherdirectory"
```

[image: error as shown below in the image]

> Test-Script : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Test-Script -Source "c:\somedirectory" -DestinationPath "c:\someotherdirectory"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-Script], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Test-Script

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`CmdletBinding()` attribute](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847872.aspx) needs to go outside the `param` block, immediately before the `param` keyword, otherwise it will simply be ignored:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetname="Directory")]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="File")]
    [switch]$file, 

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="Directory")]
    [switch]$directory,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="File")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="Directory")]
    [string]$Source,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="File")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="Directory")]
    [string]$DestinationPath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="Directory")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="File")] 
    [array]$Servers
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias!! that seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Good catch! In my mind I was already parsing the various sets haha

Comment: @briantist something in my mind started twitching when I saw `param([cmdl...` ;)